# How to run topology on storm cluster? I cant see the output log

Tags: java, cloud, bigdata, apache-storm

I'm trying to execute a topology in a cluster. I wrote a topology and compile it to a jar and then I registered it to the cluster. But for some reason it looks like the topology is not running. I just want to use Storm here as a pipeline. Registering with cmd:
`./storm jar /tmp/storm_test.jar storm.topology.MyTopology /tmp/bigFile.log`

Topology:

```
package storm.topology;

import storm.spouts.LineReaderSpout;

import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import storm.bolts.Bolt;

public class MyTopology {
    public static long tupleCounter = 0;
    public static long endTime = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.put("inputFile", args[0]);
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKERS, 4);
        config.setDebug(true);
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 10);

        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout", new LineReaderSpout());

        builder.setBolt("boltA", new Bolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");

        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("mytopology", config, builder.createTopology()); 
    }
}
```

Bolt:

```
package storm.bolts;

import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import storm.topology.MyTopology2;
import storm.spouts.LineReaderSpout;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Bolt implements IRichBolt {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    static long totalTime;
    Map<String, Integer> counters;
    private OutputCollector collector;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.counters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.collector = collector;
        this.name = context.getThisComponentId();
        this.id = context.getThisTaskId();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        //String str = input.getString(0);
        MyTopology2.tupleCounter++;
        if (input.getString(0).contains("END")) {
            MyTopology.endTime = System.nanoTime();

            System.out.println("====================================================");
            System.out.println("Number of tuples: " + MyTopology.tupleCounter);

            totalTime = MyTopology.endTime - LineReaderSpout.startTime;
            double tuplePerSec = MyTopology.tupleCounter / (totalTime / 1000000000d);
            System.out.println("Test results: " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(tuplePerSec) + "tuple/sec");
            totalTime = MyTopology2.endTime - LineReaderSpout.star`enter code here`tTime;
            System.out.println("Total run time: " + totalTime + " nsec");
            System.out.println("====================================================");
            PrintWriter writer;

            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter("/tmp/storm_results.log", "UTF-8");
                writer.println("Number of tuples: " + MyTopology.tupleCounter);
                writer.println("Test results: " + 
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(tuplePerSec) + "tuple/sec");
                writer.println("Total run time: " + totalTime + " nsec");
                writer.println("====================================================");
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestBolt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestBolt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Spout:

```
package storm.spouts;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;

public class LineReaderSpout implements IRichSpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    private FileReader fileReader;
    private boolean completed = false;
    private TopologyContext context;
    public static long startTime;

    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
            SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        try {
            this.context = context;
            this.fileReader = new FileReader(conf.get("inputFile").toString());
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file "
                    + conf.get("inputFile"));
        }
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        if (completed) {

        }
        String str;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        try {
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                this.collector.emit(new Values(str), str);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading typle", e);
        } finally {
            completed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("line"));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isDistributed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void activate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void ack(Object msgId) {
    }

    @Override
    public void fail(Object msgId) {
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local cluster and submit you topology to it, by this way you don't need set up a production cluster on remote machine, the code looks like this:

```
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("mytopology", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

Comment: It works fine with local cluster, but for some reason not on production cluster, I compiled the jar with netbeans using 1.6_35 jdk

Comment: check this document [Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html)

Answer (score 0):

In production cluster you won't see the log on console. Go the storm logs directory. There you will find worker logs file. All the logging messages are written there. Moreover in production cluster you don't see every log message. FOr that purpose you have to enable DEBUG option in config
`cfg.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG, true);`